# Python combine map with groupby and transform

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, transform

I'm having trouble combining a couple concepts in Python; groupby, map, and transform.  I have a dataframe where I'm looking to create a new column by transforming an existing one based on a group. Like this:

```
s = df[df['type'].eq('office')].groupby(['user','date']).transform('any')
df.loc[:,'type2'] = df['type'].s.map({True:'office',False:'remote'})
```

So my dataframe would look like this

```
user     date    type   type2
ron     12/1/19  office  office
ron     12/1/19  remote  office
april   12/1/19  office  office
leslie  12/1/19  remote  office
leslie  12/1/19  office  office
leslie  2/1/20   office  office
```

But I get the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 's'
```

I thought I set this up properly but having trouble getting it to work. Guidance appreciated thank you

Comment: Change `df['type'].s` to just `s`?

Comment: @QuangHoang when i do so, i get ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'``` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your code

```
s = df['type'].eq('office').groupby([df['user'],df['date']]).transform('any')
df['type2'] = s.map({True:'office',False:'remote'})
```

Comment: this edit doesn't work for me,  a keyerror occurs with groupby in the first line

Comment: i had no idea i could combine groupby like that for multiple columns! you saved me a big headache thank you !